# Dynamic equality checking of multiple properties of a type's objects

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, iequatable

I have a type like:

```
class Order
{
  public List<IItem> AllItems { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public double TotalPurchases { get; set; }
  public long Amount { get; set; }
  public int Code { get; set; }
}
```

I've implemented the `IEquatable<T>` interface to check if two objects of this type are same or not. The current `Equals` method looks like:

```
public virtual bool Equals(Order other)
{
  if ((object)other == null)
  {
    return false;
  }
  return (this.AllItems.Equals(other.AllItems)
       && this.Name.Equals(other.Name)
       && this.TotalPurchases.Equals(other.TotalPurchases)
       && this.Amount.Equals(other.Amount))
       && this.Code.Equals(other.Code));
}
```

But I wish to implement this method in such a way that it dynamically checks for equality of all the existing properties (or maybe certain properties of this type) without explicitly writing the code for comparison checks as above.

Hope I was able to express my question with clarity. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could write a custom attribute that attaches to the properties on your type which you want to be included in the comparision. Then in the Equals method you could reflect over the type and extract all the properties which have the attribute, and run a comparison on them dynamically.

Psuedo code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTarget.Property)]
class IncludeInComparisonAttribute : Attribute { }

class Order
{
    List<AllItem> Items { get; set; }

    [IncludeInComparison]
    string Name { get; set; }

    long Amount { get; set; }

    [IncludeInComparison]
    int Code { get; set; }

    override bool Equals(Order other)
    {
        Type orderType = typeof(Order);

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in orderType.GetProperties()
        {
            if (property.CustomAttributes.Includes(typeof(IncludeInComparisonAttribute))
            {
                object value1 = property.GetValue(this);
                object value2 = propetty.GetValue(other);

                if (value1.Equals(value2) == false)
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

It'll certianly need to be a bit more elaborate than that, but that should hopefully set you on the right track :)

Answer (score 1):

Two `Order`s are considered the same if all their properties are equal. It's OK for the 4 properties Name/TotalPurchases/Amount/Code, their default comparers are exactly what you want. But for the property AllItems (whose type is `List<IItem>`), you must *tell* how they consider to be equal. Currently you are using reference equals that is incorrect. `this.AllItems.Equals(other.AllItems)` should be something like:

```
this.AllItems.SequenceEqual(other.AllItems, new ItemComparer())
```

And the `ItemComparer` is a class implements `IEqualityComparer<Item>` to tell how to check if two `Item`s are equal.

Comment: I'd say you wouldn't even want to include the AllItems property in the comparison. The only properties which should be compared are the ones that make the Order unique (name? code?). Ideally it should have a unique identifier. Your advice is good though assuming he does want to compare the list :)

Comment: @Danny.. Point noted, I missed it while creating up the demo snippet :)
@Matt.. This is a demo type, the actual type does need to compare multiple properties of custom type to ascertain the equality.